# Edit range of excel charts using macros

Tags: java, vba, excel, apache-poi

I am editing an excel sheet using POI here is a sample data:

[image: Sample data]

Now there is a chart created for this data like this:

[image: Chart]

Now the number of rows of this data keeps changing everyday. So I need to set the range for this graph using macros. so how to change both series and category for a graph using macros? Or perhaps we can do it in POI itself?

Comment: See https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/two-ways-to-build-dynamic-charts-in-excel/. This is result of simple Internet search using the keywords `excel dynamic chart`. To give an answer with `apache poi` we would need more informations how `apache poi` is involved here.

Comment: Put the data into an Excel Table. Each day, the Table will be a different lingth, and the chart will adjust accordingly. See my tutorial [Easy Dynamic Charts Using Lists or Tables](https://peltiertech.com/easy-dynamic-charts-lists-tables/).